# ExcelViewer & Spring 3

Tags: excel, spring

Is is possible to use some kind of Excel viewer with Spring 3? I'm using jexcel api, and got some clues about AbstractJExcelViewer, but it uses modelmap.

I need to open a generated excel file when user clicks link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm did not get your question completely, you are looking for excel view resolvers which does not use modelMap?

The spring view resolver page has descent information:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-document

Comment: Yes, buildExcel method does  use modelmap to generate the view,